# How to bundle together data files for converting python scripts to exe using py2exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, py2exe

I need to package all the scripts into an exe to be run on windows. The code is written in python 3.6 and has imports from xlsxwriter, win32com.client, time and tkinter. The execution of the scripts is such that starting with the main.py file, calling functions from login.py by importing the module, accessing the login_cred.db for validation, and then the generate_costing.py executes through there. DesignList is a pickled list that is critical to the program. generate_costing.py also imports design_list.py for some utility functions.

Refer to this image:
[image: All the python scripts]

Now all of these scripts have to be packaged into an exe and/or dll files (not sure about how it exactly works), but majorly need to hide the contents of the scripts too, while being able to run the whole code through a single .exe file on windows if possible.

Totally at a loss here, newbie to py2exe and looking for whatever approach is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try pyinstaller and use command `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to use pyinstaller and use the --onefile argument :

```
pyinstaller --onefile foo.py
```

But if you are not comfortable with pyinstaller, you can use auto-py-2-exe that provides a graphic interface to compile your script